# Maven local dependency trying to resolve remotely

Tags: java, maven

I've installed a jar file via mvn install into my local repository

I then want to depend on this in another project/pom. This other project is trying to download the pom from the remote repositories I've setup instead of trying to resolve it from my local repository and then failing.

How do I ensure that the the local repository is checked "first"?

Comment: Do you use maven command line or do you use an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the project by checking the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" checkbox.
Guess it would solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the parent pom did not exist in the local repository. When this was added then no remote download was attempted.